# How to fix rowspan border issue when printing or converting to PDF?

Tags: html, css

I have a table in a report and one cell has rowSpan property. When converting HTML to pdf it shows the border as follows:

[image]

I added

> page-break-inside: avoid !important;

but it didn't work.

Are there any CSS properties or workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

this is a mistake.

you have to use this code

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td, table tr th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr{
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>item 1</th>
        <th>item 2</th>
        <th>item 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue when I have td with rowspan!

Comment: no. but make sure those td have a content or space